# Error building Rust from source on OS X Yosemite

Tags: rust

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro to Yosemite and I'm having trouble building Rust from source now. When I run

```
$ ./configure
$ make && sudo make install
```

it seems to build fine, but hangs on installation at this line

```
rustdoc: doc/rustc/index.html
```

and eventually outputs this error:

```
task '<main>' failed at 'failed to generate documentation: couldn't open file (permission denied (Permission denied); path=doc/implementors/graphviz/trait.GraphWalk.js; mode=open; access=read)', /Users/Raevynheart/Code/rust_projects/rust/src/librustdoc/lib.rs:246
make: *** [doc/rustc/index.html] Error 101
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I found this [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15555) that might be related, but I'm unsure how to proceed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that runs into a similar problem, here is what worked for me. If you run `make help`, you'll be presented with options for the `make` command. One of them is:

```
#   * clean - Clean the build repertory. It is advised to run this
#             command if you want to build Rust again, after an update
#             of the git repository.
```

Running `sudo make clean` and then `make && sudo make install` got Rust ready to roll once again.

Comment: Did you change your local login profile, by any chance? I upgrade recently to Yosemite and `make` went through just fine.

Comment: Not that I'm aware. It might not have had anything to do with Yosemite, but I never encountered errors building Rust from source while on Mavericks.